# Simple Select Value will not Populate via Jscript if the word is "House"

Tags: php

I have a small Project website that I am learning to code with and in this website there is a Select Dropdown Menu of Music Genres

Here is a Video to help you visualise whats happening.

youtu.be/t4cJ7TCHiN8 (of the Problem)

And another video of how I can Paste "House" into the URL and get different MYSQL results

youtu.be/zf0S9WadQXo

I select a genre post the form and the reload shows me the results.

The value of the selected Option is then automatically selected by Jscript
So the Search area and its Values remain the same as before.

I have Mainly used DocumentGetElementById or jQuery to Select the value, and I am echoing PHP variables into the DocumentGetElementById function.

There is no problems with 99.9% of the values and selectable genres, they all are automatically selected without any problems.

Just 1 Problem, The value "House" Will not select.

No matter how I try it just will not select. I have of course tried other methods, including jQuery and no matter how I alter my code or method of execution.

Nothing seems to make the value "House" populate.

Here is the code. And images to help visualise the problem.

Thank you for any help you may provide.

CODE.

```
<select id='genregrab' name='genre' class='menusmall'>
<optgroup label='Genre'>    
    <option value="">All Genres</option>
        <option value="EDM">EDM</option>
        <option value="DnB">DnB</option>
        <option value="Drum">Drum And Bass</option>
        <option value="Breakbeat">Breakbeat</option>
        <option value="Downtempo">Downtempo</option>
        <option value="Dance">Dance</option>
        <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
        <option value="Disco">Disco</option>
        <option value="Nu-Disco">Nu-Disco</option>
        <option value="House">House</option>            
        <option value="Hard">Hard House</option>
        <option value="Tech">Tech House</option>
        <option value="Techno">Techno</option>
        <option value="Deep">Deep House</option>    
        <option value="Future">Future House</option>
        <option value="Tribal">Tribal House</option>
        <option value="Tropical">Tropical House</option>
        <option value="Progressive">Progressive</option>
        <option value="Bass">Future Bass</option>
        <option value="Bounce">Future Bounce</option>
        <option value="Industrial">Industrial</option>  
        <option value="Electronic">Electronic</option>  
        <option value="Psychedelic">Psychedelic</option>
        <option value="Trance">Trance</option>
        <option value="Psy">Psy Trance</option>
        <option value="Minimal">Minimal</option>
        <option value="Ambient">Ambient</option>    
        <option value="Chillout">Chillout</option>  
        <option value="Synthwave">SynthWave</option>
        <option value="Retro">Retro</option>
        <option value="Hip">Hip-Hop</option>    
        <option value="Trip">Trip-Hop</option>
        <option value="Glitch">Glitch-Hop</option>
        <option value="Rap">Rap</option>    
        <option value="Afrobeat">AfroBeat</option>
        <option value="Grime">Grime</option>
        <option value="Trap">Trap</option>
        <option value="Trapstep">TrapStep</option>
        <option value="Dubstep">DubStep</option>
        <option value="Drumstep">DrumStep</option>
        <option value="Reggea">Reggea</option>
        <option value="RnB">RnB</option>
        <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
        <option value="Metal">Metal</option>
        <option value="Soul">Soul</option>                                                              
        <option value="Country">Country</option>
        <option value="Folk">Folk</option>                                                                  
        <option value="Jazz">Jazz</option>  
        <option value="Blues">Blues</option>
        <option value="Funk">Funk</option>  
        <option value="World">World</option>    
        <option value="Gospel">Gospel</option>  
        <option value="Latin">Latin</option>
        <option value="Ethnic">Ethnic</option>
        <option value="Bollywood">BollyWood</option>
        <option value="Moombahton">Moombahton</option>                                                              
        <option value="Orchestral">Orchestral</option>  
        <option value="Classic">Classical</option>  
        <option value="Cinematic">Cinematic</option>        
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Item Selected & POSTs Picked up By JScript to re-select the option

```
$(function(){

    var genre = document.getElementById('genregrab');
    
    var genredata = "<?php echo $genre ?>";

    genre.value=genredata;

});
```

(Of course i initially tried the following)

```
document.getElementById("genregrab").value="<?php echo $genre ?>";
```

However unlike the others , the word "House" will not be selected.

I think its to do with the word or something, as every other word will work fine.

Same process just selecting another genre, and it works fine

As you can see , the Trance genre was selected

Just the word "House" has the problem.

[image: Selecting the genre House]

And the Result after the Jscript

[image]

However , Select any other word and it works

[image]

As you can see in the image below

[image]

Any Ideas , Anybody?

I forgot to add the below code , from the GET and the MYSQL Results.
Its possible the sanitizing is effecting the variables.

The GET

```
if (isset($_GET['genre'])) {
    $genre=$_GET['genre'];
    $genre = filter_var($genre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $genre = strip_tags($genre);
    $genre = str_replace(['"',"'"], "", $genre);
} else {$genre="";}
```

And the MYSQL variable - Which also gets posted to the URL for GET

```
$genre=$row['genre']; 
 $genre = str_replace(['"',"'"], "", $genre); 
  if ($genre == "null" | $genre==" "){$genre="";}
   $genresend = explode(',',trim($genre))[0];
```

Comment: "NOTHING WORKS" - what does that mean? If this is a PHP problem, why does it contain only so little PHP code?

Comment: As in, Anything i have done to try and make the word "House" Polpulate the search bar using Jscript or Jquery has failed.

Comment: simply JavaScript compiler don't know `<?php ?>`

Comment: it does, as it is working for every other value other than "House"

Comment: Heres a Video to show what is happening

https://youtu.be/t4cJ7TCHiN8

Comment: As you can see, a Normal passing from the search bar of the value House will work, and so will any other value if selected from the product details, or Genre - However , select the Genre House from a product and it will not work. This only happens on the word House ???

Comment: And no i have not checked the HEX value, i am using utf-8

Comment: I copy&pasted your parts of the code into a local file on my system and can't reproduce the problem. As Ryan mentioned it might be an encoding problem (or something related to [White space](https://qwerty.dev/whitespace/) so your best bet would be to copy a link to an online hex editor to check for invisible characters.

Comment: Its a very confusing situation. All other Genre's Work fine, without problems. Just the word House. Its beyond Understanding..

Comment: Any errors in your console? If you hard code House in the JS does it work? E.g. `genre.value="House";`?

Comment: none. iv just figured something out though. if i COPY and PASTE the word House from a successful search and reload using the Copied word it will return a search result, The value is still not updated, but i now get a result, However if i just type word House into the url , it returns a negative result.. this is getting stranger the more i  dig into it. I think it might have something to do with the encoding so i am going to add some PHP and see if it helps.

Comment: See this video. Its really strange, but i think it will tick someone box.

https://youtu.be/zf0S9WadQXo

Comment: Reply to Ryan Vincent - You are indeed Correct, the HEX Values are different.

48 6f 75 73 65 ---&---
48 6f 75 73 d0 b5  --- So how do i adjust for this ??

Comment: No need to add `(Updated)` to your title; editing the question properly indicates that already.

Comment: Ok, so how do i Ammend the HEX or the Text correctly? and why does this Matter ?

Comment: It is about Character Sets and maybe the word that looks like 'House' on the screen really contains a special character with 'accents' on the database? I really am just guessing at this point. What to do? Check the database for the character set being used and investigate what is really in the column that contains the string that looks like 'House' but isn't. You may need assistance from some local expert about this topic.  ;-/

Comment: Ok, i see what you are saying. i have stripped the database down though because its a scrape from another website. it probably does have special characters in there somewhere , i will have to dig deeper i think. Thank you.

Comment: `if ($genre =="Housе" | $genre=="House")` - that's invalid code

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. You are more than welcome to post it as an answer instead (it's still visible in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73881975/revisions)) but your question should remain strictly a question.